# use environmentSubstitute in modified javascript

Tags: javascript, kettle

In kettle 4.4, Modified javascript step
I want to get parameters, I tried to use getVariables(var, var), but the problem is in kettle property file parameterA = somevalue, parameterB = ${parameterA}/folderB/folderC. i want to get parameterB, so If i use getVariables("parameterB"), I can only get ${ParameterA}/folderB/folderC.

Any one knows how to get the absolute parameter? I checked environmentSubstitute(), this method can substitute all the parameters, but seems not working in modified javascript step.

Comment: I personally don't like to have recursive parameter values in kettle.properties. Just user parameterB=somevalue/folderB/folderC and it's fixed.

Comment: I find a way to do this: we can call kettle internal functions to get the environmentSubstitute() function "_step_.getTransMeta().environmentSubstitute("${myparameter}")"